# adding a TextView to a TableRow

Tags: android, textview, tablerow

my program is like this

`

```
public class InfoWifiActivity<Intent> extends Activity {
    TableRow tr;
    TextView temp;

     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        wifi.startScan();
        tr = new TableRow(this);
        temp = new TextView(this);

        IntentFilter i = new IntentFilter(); 
        i.addAction(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION); 
        registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){ 

                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context,
                        android.content.Intent intent) {
                              temp.setText("SSID");
                              temp.setPadding(0,0,3,0);
                              tr.addView(temp);
}
}
}, i );
}
}
```

`

but it keeps FC when it comes to tr.addView(temp);

Can anybody help me?Thanks in advance.

Comment: whats the message in the logcat say when it force closes?

Comment: it doesnt have an error on emulator cause it doesnt have wifi data.Only in my mobile it keeps fc

Comment: So what does the logcat output show from your mobile device when it force closes?

Comment: this is the image.
I Tried showing the SSID from wifi with Toast and it works fine.So it must be a problem declaring textview or tablerow.

Comment: [link]http://i49.tinypic.com/282dz48.jpg

Comment: It looks like you've already added the view "temp" to another View parent. Double check your code to make sure that you haven't, or add an an if statement that checks to see if it already has a parent before you try to add it, and if so remove it from that parent before adding to the new one.

Comment: Saying parent you mean the "new TextView(this);"? i d really appreciate if you help me a bit more

Answer (score 0):

Try to set Height and width of TextView and then try.

```
tr.addView(temp,intWIDTH,intHEIGHT);
```

Comment: did u used any layout ? like linear or relative ?

Comment: i used relative and inside one tablerow and one button.
It would be much easier if i upload somewhere the files,to help me,wouldnt it?

Comment: tr.addview(temp,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);